# Как быстро объединить много png картинок в один jpg файл?

Tags: javascript, php, photoshop, png, jpeg

Есть 2 папки с картинками. Папка "**Правые**" и папка "**Левые**".

В этих папках лежат по 100 штук png картинок с прозрачным фоном. Итого в 2-х папках 200 png картинок.

В папке "**Правые**" - лежат картинки которые должны стоять **справа**

В папке "**Левые**" - лежат картинки которые должны стоять **слева**

Нужно объединить все эти картинки, чтоб каждая картинка из папки **"Правые"** использовала по **1 разу** все картинки из папки **"Левые"** и далее, чтоб каждая картинка из папки **"Левые"** использовала по **1 разу** все картинки из папки **"Правые"**

В каждой папке лежат те картинки, которые должны стоять в итоговом (склееном) изображении с определенной стороны - слева и справа.

**Итого должно получиться 100х100=10000 картинок.**

Как это сделать автоматически, например какими скриптами (javascript/php), или же есть в фотошопе встроенные инструменты? Пакетная обработка вроде для этого не подходит.

Comment: И где ваш код, указывающий на попытку создания решения самостоятельно?

Comment: Я установил ImageMagick на windows. На линукс не стал его ставить.

 
Сам код который запускаю через командную строку для моей задачи с помощью ImageMagick:

FOR %I IN (F:\L\*.png) DO (FOR %J IN (F:\R\*.png) DO (magick %I %J -background white -alpha remove +append -quality 75 F:\L+R\%~nI+%~nJ.jpg))


Все директории указал верно, всё лежит на своих местах! Все название png-шек на латинце.

ImageMagick вот что выдаёт и так бежит бесконечно: https://prnt.sc/t4dw7q

Может какие-то дополнительные библиотеки нужно установить?

Comment: не видит файлов. можно предположить что из-за пробелов в именах. как же виндовс разбаловал с этими пробелами. есть смысл проверить работу скрипта, убрав все пробелы в именах файлов, поскольку перебор все же происходит.